# Django HttpResponseRedirect, It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

Trying to make a form with Django and using a HttpResponseRedirect, I expected this should be fairly easy, however I seem to be doing something wrong.

I keep getting an error:

```
The view hotel.views.hotel_registration didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

In this case my guess would be that `HttpResponseRedirect` is not working properly, since, when I remove the `if` statement with the contents everything is working fine, except I can't submit a form.

I have 2 views:

```
def hotel_registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HotelRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('hotel:hotel_registered')

        else:
            form = HotelRegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'hotel/hotel-registration-form.html', {'form': form})


def hotel_registered(request):
    pass
```

And in urls.py

```
url(r'hotel-registratie/', hotel.views.hotel_registration, name='registration'),
url(r'hotel-geregistreerd/', hotel.views.hotel_registered, name='registered'),
```

These are all the parameters I have used in HttpResponseRedirect:

```
HttpResponseRedirect('hotel:hotel_registered')
HttpResponseRedirect('hotel_registered')
HttpResponseRedirect('/hotel_registered/')
HttpResponseRedirect(hotel_registered)
```

And then I rust wanted to redirect back to root:

```
HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

And using reverse:

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(hotel_registration))
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('hotel_registration'))
```

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out your exact question/problem, but I can see where your view would return None: When it's called with a method of GET.  You should try decreasing the indent level of your final return statement.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following urls.py that you posted :

```
url(r'hotel-registratie/', hotel.views.hotel_registration, name='registration'),
url(r'hotel-geregistreerd/', hotel.views.hotel_registered, name='registered'),
```

You should make the redirection using one of the following methods :

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('hotel-geregistreerd/')
```

or

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('registered'))
```

or simply

```
return redirect('registered')
```

When you use HttpResponseRedirect provide the path of the url, if you use reverse or redirect you can use the name that you defined in your urls.py.

Comment: Dont forget to import reverse and redirect with `from django.shortcuts import redirect` and `from django.urls import reverse` before using them